# What is the default scope in Node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope

There is no source code, no mention if a variable is being declared in a module

I'm not sure how to answer this precise question, I came across it in an online quiz

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/online-test/view-answer?test=nodejs&que=5

Any explanation would be helpful thanks!!

Tried searching for this question, didn't find any source that elaborates the question or provides sample code for example.

Comment: *otherwise it is global and can be accessed by this* <-- No, that's not how `this` works.

Comment: `otherwise it is global` if you are not in `strict mode`

Comment: *otherwise it is global and can be accessed by `global`*

Comment: I edited question, please take a look. @marzelin